# Is there a fast way to compute the lowest eigenvalue of this symmetric PD matrix in this specific scenario?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite

Consider

$$C = A^H D A + M$$

where

- $A$ is a $m \times m$ unitary matrix.
- $D$ is a $m \times m$ diagonal matrix with entries either $0$ or $1$. 
  The number of $1$'s is $n \ll m$.
- $M$ is a $m \times m$ diagonal matrix with all non-negative entries.

It is known that $C$ is a positive definite matrix. Is there a fast way to compute the lowest eigenvalue (need not compute the eigenvector) of $C$?

Especially given $n \ll m$ and $m$ being very large I cannot afford to compute all $m$ eigenvalues. Also I would like to avoid storing a  $m \times m$  matrix in memory if possible.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : C is PD. (otherwise  PSD means smallest eigen value is zero no?)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : if you are asking $C$ is symmetric, then yes. $C$ is symmetric positive definitive. (SPD)

Comment: How are you storing $A$ if you cannot store $m\times m$ matrices? Are you operating $Au$ implicitly?

Comment: @Y.S. :  I have a closed form expression/formula to generate entries of A. Look at D. I dont need to store entire A due to D. matrices A and M are fixed constants, D is the input to the algorithm. D is the one that varies.

Comment: @Y.S. : some approach : $B=A^HDA$ is a $m\times m$ symmetric PSD with top $n$ eigen values equal to $1$ and the remaining $(m−n)$ being zero.  $n<<m$

Comment: I guess my question is, this whole thing is easy if, for any vector $u$, $Cu$ is easy to multiply. If $C$ is diagonal then it is super easy ($O(n)$). But the $A$ poses difficulties, because that is $O(n^2)$. Are you saying that the number of nonzeros in $D$ is usually very few?

Comment: @Y.S. : Yes. Thats what I mean by $n<<m$. $D$ contains only ones and zeros. In diagonal entries of $D$, number of ones $n$ is far less than number of zeros in the diagonal.

Comment: Yeah, then I think actually @tch has the approach I would recommend. To add some clarifications, basically the power iteration works as follows: Pick any $u$, then repeatedly multiply $u =\frac{1}{\|Cu\|_2}Cu$. This will converge to the eigenvector of $C$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue, e.g. $\lambda_{\max}(C) = u^TCu$. Then, apply the same power iteration to $D = \lambda_{\max}(C)I-C$. This will give $\lambda_{\max}(D) = \lambda_{\max}(C) - \lambda_{\min}(C)$. Then you can solve for $\lambda_{\min}(C)$.

Comment: Note that every matrix-vector multiply of $Cu$ should be $O(2mn + n) \ll O(m^2)$, since your matrix has such nice structure.

Comment: @Y.S. : Can you explain what you mean by repeated multiply of $Cu$, you mean $C^nu$? I am talking about the line "Pick any u, then repeatedly multiply...."

Comment: Basically, yes. But you will do this by repeatedly running $u = Cu$ rather than $u = C^n u$ because you don't want to store $C^n$.

Comment: @Y.S. how is $Cu$ $O(2mn+n)$. multiplying with diagonal matrix I understand. but the first term of $C$ is $m\times m$. Can you please elaborate how I can do this multiplication. I guess you mean to use special properties, it would be of help if you could elaborate this. Thank you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @YS

Comment: Haha ok, sorry for disappearing. We can move to chat if you have further questions as well.

Comment: @YS as I said I have closed form expression to generate entries of A, I also already have fast algorithms for the transforms $Au$ and $A^H u$. This  solves the multiplication problem of $Cu$.

Comment: Id still like to know your approach to fast multiplication of Cu, if you have any ideas.

Comment: Well, since $D$ is diagonal and sparse, then $A^HDAu = X^HXu$ for some low rank matrix $X$ (selected by the nonzeros of $D$), so that operation should be $O(2mn)$. Then the diagonal multiply is just an elementwise multiply, so that is $O(n)$. So overall, cheaper than $O(n^2)$, no?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. One way would be inverse iteration, which is essentially power iteration with $C^{-1}$. However, this requires a solve at each step.

Another possibility is to observe that the matrix $\alpha I - C$ will has eigenvalues $\alpha - \lambda_i$ where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $C$. Therefore, if we pick $\alpha$ so that $|\alpha-\lambda_\min| > |\alpha - \lambda_i|$ for all $\lambda_i$ except $\lambda_{\min}$ the top eigenvalue of $\alpha I - C$ will correspond to the bottom eigenvalue of $C$. We can then compute the top eigenvalue of $I - \alpha C$ which will give us the smallest eigenvalue of $C$.

A simple way to ensure this is to pick $\alpha > \lambda_{\max}$. If you want, you could compute the top eigenvalue of $C$ and use this. Otherwise you could use the fact that, $\lambda_{\max}(C) \leq \lambda_\max(A^HDA) + \lambda_\max(M) \leq 1 + \lambda_\max(M)$